# Grails not working on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, grails, jvm, installation

I'm new to Grails,but i have some problems...
 so i've started to install all of what is required to make it work : jdk8, setting the JAVA_HOME variable etc.. then i've installed Grails, created a new app with it and trying to run it,without modifying it, just to see if Grails was working fine, but unfortunately, nothing happened .. not even errors..

I've tried making it work changing the jdk to 1.7 version because I’ve read that it could be the main issue, but it's still the same.. Even when i type "grails" in my console, nothing happens .. Here is my configuration :

```
| Grails Version: 3.0.11
| Groovy Version: 2.4.5
| JVM Version: 1.7.0_91
```

Thanks !

Comment: a plain grails3 call would connect to github and look for profiles there. are you behind a proxy etc, that would prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Sun Java, not openjdk (which is the default)

You can go here to see how:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/430434/replace-openjdk-with-oracle-jdk-on-ubuntu